# Is uniform convergence of a function sequence equivalent to uniform equicontinuity of the set of members of the sequence?

Tags: uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

There is a plethora of questions on this topic on Math.stackexchnge.

Can the above question be answered for $C(\mathbb R ,\mathbb R)$ with an unambiguous "yes"?

Comment: Of course not. Take the sequence fn(x)=(-1)^n

Comment: (-1)^n does not converge uniformly to anything.

Comment: But the set of functions {f(x)=1, f(x)=-1} is uniformly equicontinuous, is it not?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, yeah, suggesting equivalence is a bit weird because you can't quite recover the sequence from its support, unless the set has exactly one cluster point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it can be answered with an unambiguous “no”. Take, for instance, $f_n(x)=x+n$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Siddhartha I have already edited my answer.